# PHP autoloading helpers inside a class

Tags: php, oop, class

I currently have a manual method for registering helpers into my base connection class which goes pretty much as follows:

```
class db_con
{
    // define the usual suspect properties..

    public $helpers; // helper objects will get registered here..

    public function __construct()
    {
        // fire up the connection or die trying

        $this->helpers = (object) array();
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->helpers = null;
        $this->connection = null;
    }

    // $name = desired handle for the helper
    // $helper = name of class to be registered
    public function register_helper($name, $helper)
    {
        if(!isset($this->helpers->$name, $helper))
        {
            // tack on a helper..
            $this->helpers->$name = new $helper($this);
        }
    }

    // generic DB interaction methods follow..
}
```

Then a helper class such as..

```
class user_auth
{
    public function __construct($connection){ }

    public function __destruct(){ }

    public function user_method($somevars)
    {
        // do something with user details
    }
}
```

So after creating the `$connection` object, i would then manually register a helper like so:

```
$connection->register_helper('users', 'user_auth');
```

Now my question is, could I somehow autoload helper classes inside the base connection class? (within the `register_helper()` method or similar) Or am I limited to loading them manually  or via an external autoloader of some form?

My apologies if this question has been answered elsewhere, but I just haven't found it (not for lack of trying) and I haven't any real experience autoloading anything yet.

Any help or pointers greatly appreciated, thanks in advance! :)

**EDIT:** As per Vic's suggestion this is the working solution I came up with for the register method..

```
public function register_handlers()
{
    $handler_dir = 'path/to/database/handlers/';
    foreach (glob($handler_dir . '*.class.php') as $handler_file)
    {
        $handler_bits = explode('.', basename($handler_file));
        $handler = $handler_bits[0];
        if(!class_exists($handler, false))
        {
            include_once $handler_file;

            if(!isset($this->handle->$handler, $handler))
            {
                $this->handle->$handler = new $handler($this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This appears to include and register the objects absolutely fine for now, whether this solution is a "good" one or not, I can't know without more input or testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code could look something like below, but why would you need this?

```
 public function register_helper($name, $helper)
 {
      if(!isset($this->helpers->$name, $helper))
      {
           $this->load_class($helper);
           // tack on a helper..
           $this->helpers->$name = new $helper($this);
      }
 }

 private function load_class($class) 
 {
     if( !class_exists($class, false) ) {
          $class_file = PATH_SOME_WHERE . $class . '.php';
          require $class_file;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Basically I'm trying to keep things simple, and where possible, automated. Every table in my DB will basically have it's own associated class with methods to simplify the use of the connection methods. I'm looking for the simplest effective way of auto-magically including the helpers (contained in a specific directory) then registering them. I'll see if I can incorporate your suggested solution into a loop or something.

Comment: Working solution devised from your suggestion Vic, so taken it as accepted and updated my post. Still any further input from anyone would be more than welcome, cheers! :)

Comment: I get the helper design you want but I don't understand why the class loading part of it would be an issue. The class files in your project should be arranged so that any of the spl_autoloaders can load the class files (http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php). There's also a well defined standard regarding this matter https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

Comment: Well the class files that need to be registered in this case sit together in their own directory, are named in a sensible manner (user_auth.class.php contains user_auth etc.) I just seem to be having a hard time getting my head around using namespaces and such. I think I need to dedicate some serious time to this. I'll check the links once I've had some sleep, thanks for your input once again Vic.